# Excel VBA - Get Data from SQL based of Range - Automation Error

Tags: vba, excel

When running the below code I keep getting an Automation error, for the life of me I can't figure out why. Can anyone shed some light?

When I use the debug it highlights the below;

```
    rs.Open SQLStr, cn
```

I saw some references to

I've been tasked to get data from a SQL DB based off the values in Column A Row 3 onwards.

Example of Excel Sheet:

```
ITEM   | QTY TO PICK | QTY ON ORDER | Column 2 | Column 3 etc

PART 1 |      5      | <Data will be populated here>

PART 2 |      12     | <Data will be populated here>
```

This code runs through a Command Button.

The data pulled from SQL will be populated starting in C3 onwards.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "server=<server name>;INITIAL CATALOG=<DB Name>;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cn.Open strConn

'
'

ActiveSheet.Range("C3:G10000").Clear ' clear out existing data
Dim ItemNumber As String

ItemNumber = Range("A3").Value

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

SQLStr = "Select * from vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO = " & ItemNumber & ""

rs.Open SQLStr, cn

' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
Sheet4.Range("C3").CopyFromRecordset rs

' Tidy up

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Don't think your SQL is formatted correctly. I think it should be `SQLStr = "Select * from vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO = '" & ItemNumber & "'"`

Comment: How simple, that's solved that issue! Silly of me for not spotting it! However, the data is not getting pulled through, so back to some head scratching -_-

Comment: We've all done it :). For data issue, if nothing is returned, run the query outside of excel vba to confirm query is returning something. If it doesn't, then your issue is the query. Hope this helps

Comment: It was down to the `ItemNumber = Range("A3").Value` only running against one value at a time, not on A3:A1000 range that I need. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good spot. I was just looking at that

Answer (score 0):

As @Zac points out with incorrect use of quotes which resolves issue, consider not using quotes or variable concatenation at all by employing the industry best practice of parameterization. ADO can parameterize SQL calls using its Command [CreateParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado) method.

See below example using your setup where a `?` is used as placeholder in prepared statement, then a parameter is later appended defining its *name, type, direction size,* and *value*.

```vb
...
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM vw_WorksOrder WHERE ITEMNO = ?"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("itemparam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, ItemNumber)
End With

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = cmd.Execute
...
```

---

Also, another industry best practice is error and exception handling for runtime errors as *AutomationError* is not useful for debugging. And you want to release all `Set` objects regardless of error or not. In VBA, you can use the `On Error` handling to output more useful messages and release objects from memory accordingly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
On Error Goto ErrHandle
  '...same code but without any Set obj = Nothing (since used in ExitHandle)

ExitHandle:
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set cmd = Nothing
  Set cn = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
  Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ExitHandle

End Sub
```